# Do I need to target devices for my application?

Tags: android, layout

I finished my application, it's working as I expected on my mobile phone, however, running on different AVD it's disaster.

I have read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and this articles too: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html, but I don't know what should I do.

The min SDK is 4.0 (API 14), and I'm targeting android 4.0.3 (API 15). I want my application to run only on mobile phones. I know I can set this in AndroidManifest.XML

**Do I need to create 7 individual layouts to be compatible with different devices in portrait mode?**

My problem is with Views width, height and margins in DP. On different devices it looks different. To better understand I've attached an image:

[image]

As you can see, I marked with green the portions where the spaces are.

**What should I do to have the same design on different devices?**

**Do I need to recreate my design using RelativeLayout and reference Views between them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write the whole new code for other screens unless it should look differently in terms of positioning of elements. What you should do is define different values for different screens, for example: font size, margins, padding, etc.

For example in your case, you can make three separate dimens.xml files that will control your marginBottom attribute according to screen size that it's being displayed on.

*res/values/dimens.xml*

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default (phones) -->
    <dimen name="margin_bottom">45dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

*res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml*

```
<resources>
    <!-- 7'' tablets -->
    <dimen name="margin_bottom">65dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

*res/values-sw720dp-land/dimens.xml*

```
<resources>
    <!-- 10'' tablets -->
    <dimen name="margin_bottom">75dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

---

And then in your main .xml file you set it like this:

```
<TextView ...
    android:marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom" />
```

Comment: this is a very smart way +1 to this

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with dp here. All margins will keep same spacing (in physical units, like centimeters etc) from edges on all devices.

The problem is: some devices are having much more screen space available which is not being used.

The solution is to align the views in an appropriate place, so they don't look out of place.

I think setting `layout_gravity` to `center` would be better, than making views stick to a particular side of display.

Answer (score -1):

U should have used:

- **layout_weight and weightsum** in your layout.
- use **relative layout** (its not essential but it is encouraged)
- you could make different xml for tablets and in your manifest add them accordingly:

  ```
   res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
   res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
   res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
  ```